# Recordset Not Iterating

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am sure this is strictly user error, but for the life of me, I can not discover how to iterate a table, and write the records to Excel.  I have the below code, but it hangs on the first `Manager ID` and just repeats the write for that one constantly in a loop.  I want to iterate all the `Manager ID` in the table and write them to the same workbook.

How should I tweak this code in order to do such?

```
  Set xlR = xlWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$R$2")
  i=0
  Set rs2 = Db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TestTable ORDER BY [Manager ID] ASC", dbOpenDynaset)
  managerName = CLng(rs2.Fields(3).Value)
  Debug.Print managerName
  With rs2
     .MoveLast
     .MoveFirst
     Do While Not .EOF
        xlR.Value = .Fields(0).Value
        xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 + (i * 2)).Value = .Fields(2).Value
        xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2 + (i * 2)).Value = "ENTATH01"
        i = i + 1
        .MoveNext
     Loop
     .Close
  End With
  xlWb.SaveAs FileName:=sPath & sFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
  xlWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
  rs2.MoveNext
```

Comment: Does the debug.print output all the managernames? It looks to me like you aren't changing the destination cell (you aren't using the incremented i anywhere). Is it possible you are overwriting the same cell (R2) as you iterate over the TestTable recordset?

Comment: @majjam - a debug.print of .Fields(2).Value .Fields(1).Value and .Fields(3).Value show that the recordset is actually moving thro

Comment: This is the 3rd or 4th question this week that features `.MoveLast` followed by `.MoveFirst` ...are you guys all reading the same shitty tutorials? If you don't need the `.Count` *before you start iterating*, then you don't need to `.MoveLast` and `.MoveFirst`. Anyway seems the recordset *is* iterating, but you're overwriting the same cells over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not changing your offset, so you're continuously assigning the  same cell.

Try the following:

```
    xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=i * 3).Value
    xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1+(i*3)).Value = .Fields(2).Value
    xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2+(i*3)).Value = "ENTATH01"
```

I assume you're initializing i to 0

Comment: I altered synatx to             i = 0
            xlR.Value = .Fields(0).Value
            xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 + (i * 2)).Value = .Fields(2).Value
            xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2 + (i * 2)).Value = "E00000000"
            i = i + 1 and it is just overwriting the same 3 cells each pass - never moving over to the next column or row when the manager changes

Comment: Please move `i=0` outside of the loop

Comment: I moved the i=0 to be below this line Set xlR = xlWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$R$2") but the same result

Comment: See the adjusted answer

Answer (score 0):

Change:¨

```
i = i + 1
.MoveNext
```

to

```
i = i + 2
.MoveNext
```